# Does a user have to be logged in to use the Spotify Metadata API?

Tags: spotify

I have 2 questions regarding the Spotify Metadata API.

1) Does a user have to be logged into the Spotify Service in order to use the Metadata API to perform searches and lookups? Or is the metadata API a completely public API that can be used by anyone without having to be authenticated?

2) If the user has to be logged in, does the user have to be a premium user or can he be a non-paying Spotify user to use the metadata api?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the Web Metadata API (ws.spotify.com), then no authentication is required to use it.